# Ruby on Rails first steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I have installed ROR+apache2 on my Linux VM (TurnKey Rails VM image) and making first steps folowing http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html this guide

i have stucked on adding resource calling articles. What i have done
my routes.rb:

```
root@rails www/blog# cat ./config/routes.rb 
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :articles

  root 'welcome#index'



end
```

my rake routes

```
root@rails www/blog# rake routes
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
    articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
             POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
 new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
             PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
        root GET    /                            welcome#index
```

then folowing guide:

```
rails g controller articles
```

after that in browser "/" working fine, im getting my "hello, rails"
but "/articles/" or "/articles/new" returns 404 - not found. (The page you were looking for doesn't exist.)

my views folder

```
views  ls -al
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 5 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 10 05:02 .
drwxrwxrwx 8 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 10 04:40 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 10 05:02 articles
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 10 04:40 layouts
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 10 04:49 welcome
```

my article controller code:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
end
```

Many time spended Google has no result

The question is what am i doing wrong, and how can i debug this like issues.
Thx!

Comment: Hello! My guess is that you haven't generated any views. I might suggest taking a look at the Hartl Rails Tutorial (Google it), which does a nice job of walking beginners through many of the intro steps to getting on board with Rails.

Comment: can you show me the controller code as well :) ?

Comment: posted answer 4 your questions in topic head guys

Comment: is your articles controller empty? It shouldn't be

Comment: As mentioned in official "rails hello world" http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html empty controller isnt a reason of 404 page not found. There can be "unknown action" because of empty controller.

Answer (score 0):

The last part of the URL tells Rails which controller and which action in the controller should be called.
For your example: /actions/new refers to the controller 'actions_controller.rb' and to the action

```
def new
end
```

If you do not define something in your controller action rails will show the view which has the same name as your controller action. In this case you must have this file:

```
views\actions\new.html.erb
```

I guess this is the file you haven't created yet.

Comment: ok, i added your code in /controllers/articles_controller.rb but articles/ still 404 error

Comment: views file path should be `app/views/articles/index.html.erb` for index view (url `/articles`)